# Acessing Navigation Class properties in MVC4 View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

My Class is

```
public partial class Team
    {
        public Team()
        {
            this.Trials = new HashSet<Trials>();
            this.Users = new HashSet<Users>();
        }

        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        public string TeamDescription { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Trials> Trials { get; set; }
    }
```

and in the view I am trying to accessthe attirbutes of Trial class like

```
@model Project.Classes.Team

 <td>
         @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Trials.Count; i++ )
         {                
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Trials.ElementAt(i).Name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Trials.ElementAt(i).Name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Trials.ElementAt(i).TrialID)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.Trials.ElementAt(i).isChk)  
             <br />               
         } 
</td>
```

When view is displayed it shows the Trials objects in the model and displays on the form but when form is posted then in the controller I dont get any value for Trials it shows 0 Trials...I think I am doing some thing wrong in the binding loop ...

Any help appreciated......

Comment: Did you leave out the form in your question's code? Otherwise, that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by changing the Team calss. Instead using

```
 public virtual ICollection<Trials> Trials { get; set; }
```

I changed it to IList

```
public virtual IList<Trials> Trials { get; set; }
```

and commented the

```
 //this.Trials = new HashSet<Trials>();
```

and in the View

```
 <td>
         @for(int i=0; i<Model.Trials.Count; i++)
         {

                @Html.DisplayFor(x =>  x.Trials[i].Name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Trials[i].Name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Trials[i].TrialID)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Trials[i].isChk)  
             <br />

         }      

                </td>
```

Now I am getting the true model binging value for Team and Trials inside the team........